# Wordpress Identical Text, One Has Black Diamond Question Mark

Tags: wordpress

I have two websites that have the exact same post on them (The text was copied and pasted into both). One website shows the text fine, but the other adds in a black diamond with a question mark in the middle. It happens in more than one language, the text is exactly the same, and the sites have the same plugins installed and active. What could be causing the issue?

Comment: The encoding being used.

Comment: It's a difference in how the encoding is being interpreted. Are you viewing from different browsers?

Comment: Same browser, both sites and the database are using UTF-8.

Comment: its not the db encoding, its the declared encoding to the browser....you havent specified that character but google setting headers, there are a couple of ways to do it, its likely you will need to set in apache

Answer (score 0):

Trying to help...

- Does the page have the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` declared?
- Are both sites running in the same Web Server (version, vendor, platform)?
- Were you able to check if the Default Chatset is configured the same way in both Web Servers?